# json_normalize JSON file with list containing dictionary (sample included)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, normalize

This is a sample json file I'm working with with 2 records:

```
[{"Time":"2016-01-10",
"ID"
:13567,
"Content":{
    "Event":"UPDATE",
    "Id":{"EventID":"ABCDEFG"},
    "Story":[{
        "@ContentCat":"News",
        "Body":"Related Meeting Memo: Engagement with target firm for potential M&A.  Please be on call this weekend for news updates.",
        "BodyTextType":"PLAIN_TEXT",
        "DerivedId":{"Entity":[{"Id":"Amy","Score":70}, {"Id":"Jon","Score":70}]},
        "DerivedTopics":{"Topics":[
                            {"Id":"Meeting","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Performance","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Engagement","Score":100},
                            {"Id":"Salary","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Career","Score":100}]
                        },
        "HotLevel":0,
        "LanguageString":"ENGLISH",
        "Metadata":{"ClassNum":50,
                    "Headline":"Attn: Weekend",
                    "WireId":2035,
                    "WireName":"IIS"},
        "Version":"Original"}
                ]},
"yyyymmdd":"20160110",
"month":201601},
{"Time":"2016-01-12",
"ID":13568,
"Content":{
    "Event":"DEAL",
    "Id":{"EventID":"ABCDEFG2"},
    "Story":[{
        "@ContentCat":"Details",
        "Body":"Test email contents",
        "BodyTextType":"PLAIN_TEXT",
        "DerivedId":{"Entity":[{"Id":"Bob","Score":100}, {"Id":"Jon","Score":70}, {"Id":"Jack","Score":60}]},
        "DerivedTopics":{"Topics":[
                            {"Id":"Meeting","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Engagement","Score":100},
                            {"Id":"Salary","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Career","Score":100}]
                        },
        "HotLevel":0,
        "LanguageString":"ENGLISH",
        "Metadata":{"ClassNum":70,
                    "Headline":"Attn: Weekend",
                    "WireId":2037,
                    "WireName":"IIS"},
        "Version":"Original"}
                ]},
"yyyymmdd":"20160112",
"month":201602}]
```

I'm trying to get to a dataframe at the level of the entity IDs (extracting `Amy` and `Jon` from record 1 and `Bob`, `Jon`, `Jack` from record 2).

However I'm already getting an error early on.  Here's my code so far, assuming the sample json is saved as `sample.json`:

```
data = json.load(open('sample.json'))
test = json_normalize(data, record_path=['Content', 'Story'])
```

Results in this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I suspect it's because Content.Story is actually a list containing a dictionary, instead of dictionary itself.  But it's not clear to me how to actually get past this?

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm ultimately trying to get to the level of the entity IDs (Content > Story > DerivedID > Entity > Id).  Was showing the Content.Story code example just to illustrate where I'm at right now in figuring this out.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[['Content', 'Story']]` (As you only have one record, `Content.Story`)

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`json_normalize(data, record_path=[['Content', 'Story']])`

That should work.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I get to the level of the entity IDs though (Content > Story > DerivedID > Entity > Id)?

Comment: That should be a new question :), Please make one and comment the link here. If this helped, please upvote and mark as accepted answer :)

Comment: Okay done.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236576/json-normalize-json-file-with-multiple-levels-of-lists-containing-dictionary-sa