# json_normalize JSON file with multiple levels of lists containing dictionary (sample included)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, normalize

(Originally from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236433/json-normalize-json-file-with-list-containing-dictionary-sample-included) but re-framed for the more general question)

This is a sample json file I'm working with with 2 records:

```
[{"Time":"2016-01-10",
"ID"
:13567,
"Content":{
    "Event":"UPDATE",
    "Id":{"EventID":"ABCDEFG"},
    "Story":[{
        "@ContentCat":"News",
        "Body":"Related Meeting Memo: Engagement with target firm for potential M&A.  Please be on call this weekend for news updates.",
        "BodyTextType":"PLAIN_TEXT",
        "DerivedId":{"Entity":[{"Id":"Amy","Score":70}, {"Id":"Jon","Score":70}]},
        "DerivedTopics":{"Topics":[
                            {"Id":"Meeting","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Performance","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Engagement","Score":100},
                            {"Id":"Salary","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Career","Score":100}]
                        },
        "HotLevel":0,
        "LanguageString":"ENGLISH",
        "Metadata":{"ClassNum":50,
                    "Headline":"Attn: Weekend",
                    "WireId":2035,
                    "WireName":"IIS"},
        "Version":"Original"}
                ]},
"yyyymmdd":"20160110",
"month":201601},
{"Time":"2016-01-12",
"ID":13568,
"Content":{
    "Event":"DEAL",
    "Id":{"EventID":"ABCDEFG2"},
    "Story":[{
        "@ContentCat":"Details",
        "Body":"Test email contents",
        "BodyTextType":"PLAIN_TEXT",
        "DerivedId":{"Entity":[{"Id":"Bob","Score":100}, {"Id":"Jon","Score":70}, {"Id":"Jack","Score":60}]},
        "DerivedTopics":{"Topics":[
                            {"Id":"Meeting","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Engagement","Score":100},
                            {"Id":"Salary","Score":70},
                            {"Id":"Career","Score":100}]
                        },
        "HotLevel":0,
        "LanguageString":"ENGLISH",
        "Metadata":{"ClassNum":70,
                    "Headline":"Attn: Weekend",
                    "WireId":2037,
                    "WireName":"IIS"},
        "Version":"Original"}
                ]},
"yyyymmdd":"20160112",
"month":201602}]
```

I'm trying to get to a dataframe at the level of the entity IDs (extracting `Amy` and `Jon` from record 1 and `Bob`, `Jon`, `Jack` from record 2).  How do I do this?
To clarify, the levels are (Content > Story > DerivedID > Entity > Id)

Answer (score 2):

With a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you can reach down into that structure like:

```
with open('test.json', 'rU') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(sum([i['Content']['Story'][0]['DerivedId']['Entity']
                       for i in data], []))

print(df)
```

Or if you have a lot of data and don't want to do the clunky [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) like:

```
import itertools as it
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(it.chain.from_iterable(
    i['Content']['Story'][0]['DerivedId']['Entity'] for i in data))
```

#### Results:

```
     Id  Score
0   Amy     70
1   Jon     70
2   Bob    100
3   Jon     70
4  Jack     60
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  If I want to add meta data using the pandas json_normalize function how would that be done?

Comment: I don't know that function well, and you have not shown what output you are hoping for, so... I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(data, ['Content', 'Story', 'DerivedId', 'Entity'])
print(df)
```

remember, the final root must be a list in your json

### Results:

```py
     Id  Score
0   Amy     70
1   Jon     70
2   Bob    100
3   Jon     70
4  Jack     60
```

if you want just id

```py
df[['Id']]
```