# Building pandas dataframe from JSON

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe from a mongoDB collection dump.

I have referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236433/json-normalize-json-file-with-list-containing-dictionary-sample-included) to normalize my data but it doesn`t help. The output doesn`t contain the filename and id.

I would like to have filename and id in my dataframe.

Here is my json sample

```
[
    {'FileName': '32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp',
     '_id': {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew33'},    
     'section_details': [{'content': 'Efficient Algorithms for Non-convex Isotonic '
                                     'Regression through Submodular Optimization  ',                                 
                          'heading': 'title'},
                         {'content': 'We consider the minimization of submodular  '
                                     'functions subject to ordering constraints. We show that '
                                     'this potentially non-convex optimization problem can  '
                                     'be cast as a convex optimization problem on a space of  '
                                     'uni-dimensional measures',
                          'heading': 'abstract'},
                         {'content': '', 'heading': 'subject'},
                         {'content': ' Introduction to convex optimization'
                                     'with mean ',
                          'heading': 'Content'}]},
    {'FileName': '32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp',
     '_id': {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew11'},    
     'section_details': [{'content': 'Text-Adaptive Generative Adversarial Networks:  '
                                     'Manipulating Images with Natural Language ',
                          'heading': 'title'},
                         {'content': 'This paper addresses the problem of manipulating '
                                     'images using natural language description. Our  '
                                     'task aims to semantically modify visual  '
                                     'attributes of an object in an image according  '
                                     'to the text describing the new visual',
                          'heading': 'abstract'},
                         {'content': '', 'heading': 'subject'},
                         {'content': ' Introduction to Text-Adaptive Generative Adversarial Networks',
                          'heading': 'Content'}]}
]
```

Expected output

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if you are willing to have the output as:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import json
>>> j = [
...     {'FileName': '32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp',
...      '_id': {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew33'},
...      'section_details': [{'content': 'Efficient Algorithms for Non-convex Isotonic '
...                                      'Regression through Submodular Optimization  ',
...                           'heading': 'title'},
...                          {'content': 'We consider the minimization of submodular  '
...                                      'functions subject to ordering constraints. We show that '
...                                      'this potentially non-convex optimization problem can  '
...                                      'be cast as a convex optimization problem on a space of  '
...                                      'uni-dimensional measures',
...                           'heading': 'abstract'},
...                          {'content': '', 'heading': 'subject'},
...                          {'content': ' Introduction to convex optimization'
...                                      'with mean ',
...                           'heading': 'Content'}]},
...     {'FileName': '32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp',
...      '_id': {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew11'},
...      'section_details': [{'content': 'Text-Adaptive Generative Adversarial Networks:  '
...                                      'Manipulating Images with Natural Language ',
...                           'heading': 'title'},
...                          {'content': 'This paper addresses the problem of manipulating '
...                                      'images using natural language description. Our  '
...                                      'task aims to semantically modify visual  '
...                                      'attributes of an object in an image according  '
...                                      'to the text describing the new visual',
...                           'heading': 'abstract'},
...                          {'content': '', 'heading': 'subject'},
...                          {'content': ' Introduction to Text-Adaptive Generative Adversarial Networks',
...                           'heading': 'Content'}]}
... ]
>>> pd.DataFrame(j)
                                       FileName                                   _id                                    section_details
0  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew33'}  [{'content': 'Efficient Algorithms for Non-con...
1  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew11'}  [{'content': 'Text-Adaptive Generative Adversa...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `json_normalize` method can be passed an array of meta data to add to each record.

Here, assuming that js contains the data from your original json, you could use:

```
df = json_normalize(js, 'section_details',['FileName', '_id'])
```

You will get:

```
                                       FileName                                   _id                                            content   heading
0  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew33'}  Efficient Algorithms for Non-convex Isotonic R...     title
1  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew33'}  We consider the minimization of submodular  fu...  abstract
2  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew33'}                                                      subject
3  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew33'}      Introduction to convex optimizationwith mean    Content
4  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew11'}  Text-Adaptive Generative Adversarial Networks:...     title
5  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew11'}  This paper addresses the problem of manipulati...  abstract
6  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew11'}                                                      subject
7  32252652D.article.0018038745057751440210.tmp  {'$oid': '5ced0669acd01707cbf2ew11'}   Introduction to Text-Adaptive Generative Adve...   Content
```

After that, you will still have to fix the `_id` column and pivot the dataframe. At the end you could end with:

```
# extract relevant infos
df = json_normalize(js, 'section_details',['FileName', '_id'])

# fix _id column
df['_id'] = df['_id'].apply(lambda x: x['$oid'])

# pivot to get back the expected columns
resul = df.groupby('FileName').apply(lambda x: x.pivot(
    '_id', 'heading', 'content')).reset_index().rename_axis('', axis=1)
```

Alternatively, you could directly build a dataframe row *by hand* from each row from the original json:

```
resul = pd.DataFrame([dict([('FileName',j['FileName']), ('_id', j['_id']['$oid'])]
                           +list({sd['heading']: sd['content'] for sd in j['section_details']
                                 }.items())) for j in js]).reindex(columns=['FileName',
                                            '_id', 'title', 'abstract', 'subject', 'Content']
```