# Converting an API response into Python Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, api

Dear community experts

I have an API returning the following structure that I need to convert into a pandas data frame.
How could I do to create such Data Frame?.

Thanks, Hernan

```
[{'quoteSymbol': 'USDT',
  'baseSymbol': 'ETH',
  'orderBooks': [{'exchange': 'Bittrex',
    'orderBook': {'asks': [{'price': '2112.20173745',
       'quantity': '1.41879654'},
      {'price': '2112.38300246', 'quantity': '1.41868464'},
      {'price': '2112.56760000', 'quantity': '0.00209173'}],
     'bids': [{'price': '2111.08708148', 'quantity': '1.41874566'},
      {'price': '2110.87591399', 'quantity': '1.41874566'},
      {'price': '2110.73500000', 'quantity': '2.35200000'}]}},
   {'exchange': 'Binance',
    'orderBook': {'asks': [{'price': '2092.91000000',
       'quantity': '27.01387000'},
      {'price': '2092.96000000', 'quantity': '3.34463000'},
      {'price': '2092.97000000', 'quantity': '8.13200000'}],
     'bids': [{'price': '2112.52000000', 'quantity': '1.45438000'},
      {'price': '2112.36000000', 'quantity': '0.45074000'},
      {'price': '2112.35000000', 'quantity': '0.97545000'}]}},
   {'exchange': 'Bitstamp', 'orderBook': None}]}
```

Comment: What do you want the dataframe to be? Like what columns do you want and how do they map from the JSON?

Comment: columns: quote symbol, base symbol, exchange, order type(asks/bids), price, quantity; 

orderBook

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236433/json-normalize-json-file-with-list-containing-dictionary-sample-included

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to first transform the JSON you have into a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary should have keys that correspond to the columns you want in the final dataframe.

Comment: @HernanN I suggest starting small. Perhaps by creating a list with dictionaries that have `'price'` and `'quantity'`. Alternatively, you can start by making a list with just `'quote_symbol'` and `'base_symbol'`. The point is to break the problem down into smaller parts that you can figure out how to solve then take the next piece that you can solve, etc.

Comment: @HernanN You may want to break it down even smaller than my previous comment. If you get the API response as a string, you need to parse it into a list. If you already have a list, you need to iterate over that list. For example, as a first step, you can parse the JSON and then loop over the list printing out each element.